# Find the Greatest Common Divisor

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

Here is the question.
Find the greatest common divisor of two positive integers. The integers can be large, so you need to find a clever solution.

The inputs x and y are always greater or equal to 1, so the greatest common divisor will always be an integer that is also greater or equal to 1.

Here is my solution.

```js
function mygcd(x, y) {
  //your code here

  let gcd = [];

  let lowestNum;
  let bigestNum;

  //detect the lowest and bigest numbers
  if (x < y) {
    lowestNum = x;
    bigestNum = y;
  } else if (x > y) {
    lowestNum = y
    bigestNum = x;
  } else {
    lowestNum = x
  }

  //check if the bigest num has a modolo == 0
  //else loop the lowest num and push in the array
  if (bigestNum % lowestNum === 0) {
    return gcd += lowestNum;
  } else {
    let arrNum = []
    for (let i = 1; i < lowestNum; i++) {
      // console.log(i)
      arrNum.push(i)
    }

    //loop the array backwards
    for (i = arrNum.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
      if (lowestNum % arrNum[i] === 0 && bigestNum % arrNum[i] === 0) {
        console.log(arrNum[i])
        if (gcd !== 0) {
          return
        } else {
          //          gcd += arrNum[i]
          let vals = gcd.push(arrNum[i])
          console.log(typeof(vals))
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(gcd)
  return gcd[0];
}

console.log(mygcd(30, 12))
```

The above solution works for the test cases i tried it for, but the issue is that it returns the correct divisor and undefined.

This is what my logs look like

```
6
undefined
6
undefined
```

The test cases

test:
Log

```
6
expected undefined to equal 6
```

so it gets undefined instead of 6 or the correct divisor.

I also tired a different recursive approach below.
Note: This works well.

```js
function mygcd(x, y) {
  if (!x) return y
  if (!y) return x

  return mygcd(y, x % y)
}
console.log(mygcd(30, 12))
console.log(mygcd(8, 12))
```

But i am curious to understand why my original solution breaks. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: At the end of your method, you call `console.log(gcd);`, which prints `6`. Then you `return gdc[0]` (`6[0]`, which is `undefined`), and you `console.log` that

Comment: Your code has more than one problem. Treating arrays as numbers, misunderstanding the value that `push` returns, returning nothing, not defining `i` as local in one of the loops, leaving `bigestNum` undefined when arguments are equal, storing sequential numbers in an array only to iterate them, pushing to an array, when in the end you have nothing useful for those items except the first one, ...etc

Comment: `return gcd[0];` is never reached, you log the value here `console.log(arrNum[i])` and then `return` nothing, hence `undefined`

Comment: `+=` does not append to an array. You need to decide what you want `gcd` to be. A number? An array? A string?

Comment: @deceze and array actually

Comment: Then don't use `+=` on it…!?

Comment: A mistake, thanks @deceze